# Finding a simple basis of a subspace of $R^{N}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have some basis of a subspace in $R^{N}$. I would like to find a new basis that is as simple as possible, meaning one that contains vectors that have as many zero elements as possible.

I expect that I need some kind of matrix decomposition to achieve this. Are there any known methods that achieve this? I don't necessarily need a basis with the most zeroes possible, just some way to improve simplicity.

Say my current basis vectors are $x_{i}$ for $i=1,..m<n$ where $n$ is the dimension of my space. Call the new basis $y_{i}$ that I do not know yet. I need to find a matrix $M$ such that $(x_{1},...,x_{m})M = (y_{1},...,y_{m})$

Comment: You want to diagonalize the operator. Look up Jordan form and similar decompositions. Best wishes.

Comment: I don't understand how the Jordan normal form helps me. I'll edit what (I think) I am looking for in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert on these kind of "optimization" problems, but here is what I can say.

[EDIT.] I think **Part 2.** of this "algorithm" is in fact quite useless, because, if you already have a basis for your subspace $V$ you'd better apply **Part 3.** which I'm adding now.

**Part 1.** First of all, if your subspace $V \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ was given by a set of cartesian equations,

$$
AX = 0 \ ,
$$

then, getting the reduced row-echelon form of matrix $A$,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & a^1_{r+1} & \dots &  a^1_n \\
0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & a^2_{r+1} & \dots &  a^2_n  \\
\dots   \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & a^r_{r+1} & \dots &  a^r_n  \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0         & \dots &  0  \\
\dots  \\
0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0         & \dots & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

would allow you to obtain some of the unknowns as function of the others. Here $r$ is the rank of $A$.  Namely,

\begin{eqnarray*}
x_1 &=& - (a^1_{r+1} x_{r+1} + \dots + a^1_{n}x_n) \\
x_2 &=& - (a^2_{r+1} x_{r+1} + \dots + a^2_{n}x_n ) \\
\dots  \\
x_r &=& - (a^r_{r+1} x_{r+1} + \dots + a^r_{n}x_n )
\end{eqnarray*}

So, you would obtain a basis for your vector subspace with lots of zeros, because any vector of it could be written as

$$
(x_1, \dots , x_r, x_{r+1}, \dots , x_n) = x_{r+1}(-a^1_{r+1}, \dots, -a^r_{r+1}, 1, 0, \dots , 0) + x_2(-a^2_1, \dots, -a^2_n, 0, 1, 0, \dots , 0) +\dots + x_{n} (-a^r_1, \dots , -a^r_n, 0, \dots , 0, 1) \ .
$$

That is,

\begin{eqnarray*}
u_1 &=& (-a^1_{r+1}, \dots, -a^r_{r+1}, 1, 0, \dots , 0) \\
u_2 &=& (-a^2_1, \dots, -a^2_n, 0, 1, 0, \dots , 0) \\
\dots && \\
u_d &=& (-a^r_1, \dots , -a^r_n, 0, \dots , 0, 1) \ ,
\end{eqnarray*}

with $d = n-r$, would be a basis for your vector subspace with a pretty amount of zeros everywhere.

**Part 2.** But you don't start with a system of cartesian equations, do you? -Instead, you already have a bais for your $V$. Well, then you should obtain first a system of linear equations for it. For instance, like this: if $v_1, \dots , v_d$ is your basis, then any vector $u\in V$ can be written as

$$
u = \lambda_1 v_1 + \dots + \lambda_d v_d \ .
$$

(Hence $d$ is the dimension of $V$.) If

$$
v_1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
a^1_1 \\
\vdots \\
a^n_1
\end{pmatrix}
\ , \dots , 
v_d =
\begin{pmatrix}
a^1_d \\
\vdots \\
a^n_d
\end{pmatrix}
$$

were the coordinates of your basis vectors, then this would mean that the $\lambda_i$ up there of your

$$
u =
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
\vdots  \\
x_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$

would be the solution of this linear system of equations:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a^1_1 & \dots & a^1_d \\
\vdots &      & \vdots \\
a^n_1 & \dots & a^n_d
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1  \\
\vdots  \\
\lambda_d
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\
\vdots  \\
x_n
\end{pmatrix}  \ .
$$

Ok, so now reduce to row-echelon form this system,

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
* & \dots & * & | & g_1(x_1, \dots , x_n) \\
\vdots &   &\vdots & | & \\
* & \dots & * & | & g_d(x_1, \dots , x_n) \\
0 & \dots & 0 & | & g_{d+1}(x_1, \dots , x_n) \\
\vdots &  &\vdots & | & \\
0 & \dots & 0 & | & g_n(x_1, \dots , x_n) \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and you'll get a linear system of equations for your subspace. Namely,

$$
g_{d+1}(x_1, \dots , x_n)= 0 \ , \dots , \ g_n(x_1, \dots , x_n) = 0 \ ,
$$

to which you can apply part 1.

**Example.** Let's say you have $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ given by a basis like

$$
v_1 = (1,-1,0) , v_2 = (1,1, 0) \ .
$$

So, clearly $V$ is the $xy$-plane and we could safely produce a "simple" basis with no computations at all, just taking

\begin{eqnarray*}
u_1 &=& (1,0,0) \\
u_2 &=& (0,1,0)
\end{eqnarray*}

But let's see how our "algorithm" works, nevertheless. First we use the second part to produce a system of linear equations for $V$:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1  &  1  & | & x  \\
-1 &  1  & | & y  \\
0  &  0  & | & z
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Adding the first row to the second, you get

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1  &  1  & | & x  \\
0  &  2  & | & x +y  \\
0  &  0  & | & z
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Which is already in row-echelon form, so functions $g_i$ are in this case

$$
g_1(x,y,z) = x \ , \  g_2(x,y,z) = x + y  \quad \text{and} \quad g_3(x,y,z) = z \ .
$$

The only one that matters for us is the last one: $z = 0$. Now, we apply part 1 and get from here that all vectors of $V$ have the following form

$$
(x,y,0) = x (1,0,0) + y (0,1,0) \ ,
$$

for arbitrary values of $x,y$. So the "simple" basis of $V$ is, indeed,

$$
u_1 = (1,0,0) \quad \text{and} \quad u_2 = (0,1,0) \ .
$$

**Part 3.** If you have a basis $v_1, \dots , v_d$ for $V$ with coordinates as in **Part 2.**, you just put together all your vectors as the columns of a matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
a^1_1 & \dots & a^1_d \\
\vdots &      & \vdots \\
a^n_1 & \dots & a^n_d
\end{pmatrix}

and then reduce it to its reduced row-echelon form, but by means of elementary **column** transformations, instead of row ones. Since elementary transformations are the same as linear combinations and they preserve the rank of the matrix, you won't change the subspace generated by $v_1, \dots , v_d$, that is, $V$. And in the end, you'll get a basis with plenty of zeros too. Something like

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1      & 0      & \dots   & 0      \\
0      & 1      & \dots   & 0      \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & 0      \\
0      & 0      & \dots   & 1      \\
b^d_1  & b^d_2  & \dots   & b^d_d  \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots  \\
b^n_1  & b^n_2  & \dots   & b^n_d
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Applying this new "algorithm" to the same example, this time we get:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1  & 1   \\
-1  & 1   \\
0  & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
1  &  0  \\
-1  & 2   \\
0  &  0
\end{pmatrix}
\longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
1  & 0   \\
-1  & 1   \\
0  & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\longrightarrow
\begin{pmatrix}
1  &  0  \\
0  &  1  \\
0  &  0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Here the elementary column transformations have been the following:

- Substract the first column from the second one.
- Divide the second column by $2$.
- Add the second column to the first one.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer. There are some things that are unclear for me:

Comment: - What is $r$? At the end of part 2, you mention $n-r$ equations that describe my subspace. Yet, in part 1, A has $r$ rows, which would correspond with $r$ linear equations right?

- After "any vector of it could be written as", you split up some vector, but I don't see how you would get to the form you show using the previous equations.

- Where do the functions $g_{i}$ come from? I am familliar with the row Echelon form, but I don't see how functions of $x$ would appear.

Comment: $r$: I'm afraid I've been using too many $r$'s there. Let me make some changes in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answers. Hope that it helps. Nevertheless, now I see a simpler "algorithm" for your "simpler" basis. Let me think for a minute, and I will write it.

Comment: Sorry for my misleading first attemp. It's the consequence of thinking first of **Part 1.** It's not wrong, but you just do some useless work with it.

Comment: Thank for the corrections. The algorithm in part 3 makes a lot of sense. I would think that any further improvement would be caused by 'accidental' cancellations in the elements of the vectors that are below the diagonal. Do you think there's any method that could reorder the coordinates of the vectors (i.e. switching dimensions around) that might improve the likeliness of finding such cancellations?

Comment: I don't think so. Once you have a diagonal in the upper part you cannot "touch" anything without ruining that diagonal -you're not allowed to do *row* elementary transformations in part 3.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. What I mean is that this method introduces a bias towards the upper elements of the vectors. I could, for instance, flip the vectors around (make the last elements the first, and etc.), then do the transform, and then flip them back. That way, I might end up with more zeroes, because I am reducing the basis with respect to different elements.

Comment: Nope. You cannot change the order of the coordinates.

Comment: Maybe my last statement deserves a comment. You cannot change the order of the coordinates because $(1,0)$ is not the same as $(0,1)$. For the same reason, you cannot do elementary *row* transformations: you would be changing the basis of your vectors. And there is nothing else that can be done once you have arrived at a matrix like the last one (I should have said that the $1$'s might not be along the main diagonal, but perhaps some steps down) because it's a *reduced* row-echelon form. And for every matrix the *reduced* row-echelon form is *unique*.

Comment: I don't think I'm making myself clear. Another example: I could come up with a similar algorithm as one that finds the row-echelon form, but that would create a identity matrix in the bottom half of the matrix, instead of the top half. I would find a basis that has the same amount of zeroes, but there might be cancellations in the area's that are not the identity matrix, that I wouldn't have found through the regular row-echelon algorithm.

Comment: The only thing you can do with a basis of a vector subspace $V$ -without ruinning the fact that it's a basis of $V$- are linear combinations of elementary transformations kind. With these elementary transformations the best you can get, to the best of my knowledge, is the reduced row-echelon form. Which is unique for every matrix. So, I don't see what else you can do to obtain more zeros in your basis.